# Xl4015 5A for 2s 18650 as charger

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, module

I have a xl4015 5A with only voltage adjuster. Can I use it for charging 2 series and 2 parallel 18650 cells?
I saw a circuit diagram but in that diagram the xl4015 has variable current adjuster. It was set to 2A. In picture circuit diagram the xl4015 has current adjuster. [image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic or draw a block diagram, you also have no links to datasheets

Comment: Exactly which '18650' cells will you be using?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't use a power supply with constant output voltage to charge lithium batteries. Or if you can, it's not the intended purposes of a constant output voltage supply, and it might not be safe.

A BMS is not a charger either.

You really need something between 12V and the BMS that is a charger that can safely charge the lithium batteries according to what the battery chemistry requires in order to  not damage and maybe explode and start a fire.

Comment: No, I have xl4015 to charge the cells. In the above diagram this xl4015 has potentiometers for both voltage and current. And xl4015 I have has only potentiometer for voltage and it has variable current between 0-5A. So I want to ask that can I use xl4015 I already have or I will have to buy one with both potentiometers. The above circuit diagram, that person set voltage to 8.4v and current to 2A to charge 2s2p 18650 cells

Comment: If your module has only voltage adjustment, then it does not have constant current mode and it cannot be used to charge lithium batteries as it is not a charger.

Comment: then I need current potentiometer too in xl4015?

Comment: what is the purpose of the current potentiometer on the module?